# How to play and stop songs from assets in flutters?

Tags: flutter, dart

Exception has occurred.
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method disposeAllPlayers on channel com.ryanheise.just_audio.methods))

In every audio flutter packages, Exception occured

Comment: Did you rerun the app after adding the package? Stop the current process and run it again.

Comment: Yup done that several times, still error

Answer (score 0):

try with uninstall and install app again it will remove  **MissingPluginException**

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly do you mean by app, Imports or something else?